# How to hide tablix in ssrs? getting error message when doing preview

Tags: reporting-services

I have a requirement to hide tablix based on condition

in the properties of tablix I am using below

=iif(Fields!ClosedDate.Value<"2015-07-01","True","False")

whenever ClosedDate is less than 2015-07-01 I want to show tablix to load data into report. whenever ClosedDate is greater than 2015-07-01 I want to hide tablix to load data into report

but when I am doing preview I am seeing error "the hide expression used in tablix 'Tablix2' returned a data type that is not valid"

please can anyone  suggest what is the error in the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iif evaluates an expression to return True or False which are Boolean values not strings. Remove the quotes!

```
=iif(Fields!ClosedDate.Value<"2015-07-01",True,False)
```

Also, make sure to set the language property on your report, otherwise you may find 2nd Jan being evaluated as 1st Feb

Comment: Thanks! how do I set language property?

Comment: On the Properties panel select the Report item from the drop down box. Then find the Language property. Set it to a value that matches your location (eg en-GB)

Comment: Thanks very much. One addition to the above expression. in the same expression I need to add one more condition. I want to hide tablix completely on or after we reach 30/12/2016. this condition does not depend on ClosedDate no matter of whatever ClosedDate I want to hide Tablix completely once we reach the date 30/12/2016. is it possible to add this condition to above expression?

Comment: Yes, you can nest conditional logic just so:  `=Iif(   Today > "2016-12-30",
 True,
 Iif(
  Fields!TodayDate.Value < "2015-07-01",
  True,
  False
 )
)`